# Many to many table rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm trying to set up a many to many table using rails. I followed [these instructions from the Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) and believe I have the schema set up properly.

I would like to be able to see all reviews for a specific doctor.

models:

```
class Doctor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
  has_many :users, through: :reviews
end

class Review <ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :doctor
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
  has_many :doctors, through: :reviews
end
```

I'm able to successfully query `doctor.users`, `user.doctors`, and `user.reviews`. However when I try to query `doctor.reviews` I only see an empty proxy `#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>`

How can I see all reviews for a doctor?

Comment: What you have looks fine. Are you sure there is actually data to return? `doctor.users` could not return any records if `doctor.reviews` returns no records.

Comment: Are you sure it is empty? Maybe this answer is only saying what type of answer you are getting, which is correct. Check doctor.reviews.count.

Comment: @JoaoCunha Interesting. It is empty, but doctor.reviews.count returns 1.

Comment: Well, so it's not empty =) What you get if you run doctor.reviews[0] ?

Comment: @JoaoCunha :). I get nil

Comment: Sorry man, that's really strange. I tried to reproduce here, but whenever I receive <ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []> the count method is always 0. Have no idea of what's going on there. I've Tried to force a relationship with only on side of information, but that does not seem to be the problem. Anyway, I think you should do queries comparing rails queries and queries directly in database using pgAdmin, if postgresql.

Comment: @JoaoCunha I appreciate it. I'll keep working through it and I'll let you know!

Comment: Drop into Rails console (or call `reload!` on the current console) and run your model queries again, then call your associations, e.g. `doctor.reviews`. Post all console output since `reload!` into your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
  has_many :doctors, through: :reviews
end
```

to:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
  has_many :doctors, through: :reviews, source: :doctor
end
```

What is happening is that user is looking for "doctors" inside of Reviews, but you have no method to retrieve "doctors" only "doctor". If you specify the source attribute, it will name your query "doctors" but it will look under "doctor" which in this case *is* defined. Rails tries to guess what it should be, and usually assumes correctly, but being more explicit may solve the problem in this case.

Comment: (Unless I'm missing something) You shouldn't need the `source` option. Rails can infer the association name from the plural. Ultimately, since the relationship is going "through" reviews, Rails knows to join users to reviews on `reviews.user_id`, and then join doctors to reviews on `reviews.doctor_id`, thus returning all the doctors that have been reviewed by this user.